# How can i present efficiently 10000 record list in single html file

Tags: javascript

I have single html file that contains 10000 list items that needs to be in single html file 
order by categories for example ordered by the ABC not all of them needs to be shown.
each time only 500 ( so the other are hidden ) .
what way or method can efficiently rearrange me the list in this way ?
java script ? css?

its all in client side , no server side.

Comment: most definitely cannot do this with CSS, and you're better off doing it with a server-side language.

Comment: also, this is the wrong type of `list` for the tag

Comment: Can you use Ajax to retrieve your data or you have all 10.000 file every time you reload the page?

Comment: Detail your question please. Is there a server side or this HTML file is just a document?

Comment: You would want to detach the list (UL element) from the DOM. You can then rearrange the LI elements while the list is "offline", and then append it back to the DOM once you're finished with it.

Comment: Šime Vidas  what do you mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to alphabetize your list:

```
var list = document.getElementById("myList");
var listItems = [].map.call(list.getElementsByTagName("li"), function(item) {
    return { text: text(item), element: item };
});
function sortList() {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    listItems = listItems.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.text < b.text ? -1 : b.text < a.text ? 1 : 0;
    });
    listItems.forEach(function (item) {
        frag.appendChild(item.element);
    });
    list.innerHTML = "";
    list.appendChild(frag);
}
function text(el) {
    var s = el.innerText;
    if (!s && s != "") {
        s = el.textContent || "";
    }
    return s.toLowerCase();
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4bm57/6/

To filter the list:

```
function filterList() {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    listItems.forEach(function (item) {
        if ([filter criteria code here]) {
            frag.appendChild(item.element);
        }
    });
    list.innerHTML = "";
    list.appendChild(frag);
}
```

This code uses Array methods not available in some older browsers.  For this code to work in IE8 or earlier, see the compatibility sections for [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility) and [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

A Datatable with Pagination is way to go.

**Below example** is a JSF component but I think it is good enough to give you the idea.

**Example:** [**DataTable Handling Large Data**](http://www.openfaces.org/demo/datatable/DataTable_handlingLargeData.jsf)

Answer (score 1):

I would reccommend that you look at [KnockoutJs](http://knockoutjs.com/).  It has all the features you may want.

1. It is designed to work with significant amounts of data that is client side.
2. You can dynamically create grids of different completely formats easily by using differing templates to display you data. See http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/quick-tip-dynamically-changing.html.
3. You can implement live searching easily.  See http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/cCBqJ/ for example.  Using this example, you can also implement custom filtering to only display the data of interest.
4. You can implement any sort of dynamic sorting you would like.  See http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/93Z8N/ for a simple example.  You can also chain output of filter into sort routine.
5. You can implement pagination easily by chaining a paging filter after the sorting function.

So you can easily slice and dice and show the data anyway you would like.

Downside is that there are not current a single open source project to that support generalized grids with sorting, filtering and client side paging.  There are various partial implementations.  Best information is at http://www.knockmeout.net/ and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/knockoutjs.

I'm currently using all of the above features in my current project.  KnockoutJs does have a learning curve.  But I found it the best way to do this type of data presentation.

Comment: Normally, the limiting factor on speed is the number of elements that are displayed at one time.  This is where using paging to limit the amount of data shown helps speed things up.  But by slow, what do you mean?